# How to generate different html content depending on http results in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When my page loads I want to make an http call to the server to see if the user's login session is still valid.  The client will send a session key with the current timestamp, and server will compare that timestamp to see if it is longer than its specified timeout period. The server will then return either true or false.

If the http call returns true and the login is valid I want to generate this html:

```
<li><a href='#logout'>logout</a></li>
```

If the call returns false and the login has expired I want to show the following:

```
<li><a href='#login'>login</a></li>
```

I am not sure how to do this with AngularJS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular has built-in directives for conditional rendering:

`ng-show` / `ng-hide`: conditionally set `display: none` style (with `.ng-hide` class)

`ng-if` / `ng-switch`: conditionally add/remove DOM elements.

Either approach would work here. For example:

```
<li ng-switch="isLoggedIn">
  <a ng-switch-when="true"  href='#logout'>logout</a>
  <a ng-switch-when="false" href='#login'>login</a>
</li>
```

`isLoggedIn` can be set whenever you complete the HTTP call.

Answer (score 1):

Create a controller

```
angular.module('yourModuleName').controller('sessionCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
    $http.get('url')
        .success(function(data){
            $scope.loggedIn = data ? '#logout' : '#login'; //true or false 
        })
}]);
```

And then in your markup

```
<div ng-controller="sessionCtrl"> 
    <li ng-show="loggedIn"><a href='{{loggedIn}}'>logout</a></li>
</div>
```

**EDIT:** You can use ng-if/ng-switch instead of ng-show to optimise performance because this will actually remove the dom object instead of hiding it.  However, in your case it shouldn't matter too much. Furthermore, keep in mind if you're using a version below 1.2, you may not get access to ng-if. ng-switch is also somewhat verbose.

Comment: I'd vote for ng-switch, or ng-if and avoid even generating the templates not used.